# Operations between list objects in R with apply function

Tags: r, list, loops, apply, lapply

I have a *1x5* matrix `A` and a list of 5 `B` with matrices (*double [100x100]*) in `R`. Each argument of A corresponds to one B  and I want to create the following function

`C = ( max(A[,i],A[,j]) * B[[i]] * B[[j]] ) / 2`

for example to calculate C between 1 and 2 I can use the following

```
set.seed(123)
A <- matrix(c(5.2,6.9,32,40,8.3), ncol = 5 )

B <- list(matrix(rnorm(100 * 100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 100, 100), 
          matrix(rnorm(100 * 100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 100, 100), 
          matrix(rnorm(100 * 100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 100, 100), 
          matrix(rnorm(100 * 100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 100, 100), 
          matrix(rnorm(100 * 100, mean = 0, sd = 1), 100, 100))

C_1.2<- max(A[,1],A[,2]) * (unlist(B[[1]])*unlist(B[[2]]))
```

I want to create a list in `R` that does the above for all possible combinations with the use of an `apply` function? I want the names to be `C_j.j`. I manage to it as follows:

```
combinations <- combn(1:5, 2)

result_list <- lapply(1:ncol(combinations), function(i){
  j <- combinations[1, i]
  k <- combinations[2, i]
  
  C <- (max(A[, j], A[, k]) * B[[j]] * B[[k]]) / 2
  
  list(C)
})

names(result_list) <- paste0("C_", combinations[1, ], ".", combinations[2, ])
```

However I can't produce the `C_1.1`, `C_2.2`,`C_3.3`,`C_4.4`,`C_5.5`. How can I fix that? I am thinking when i=j, then to calculate `C_i.i <- (A[,i] * B[[i]]^2) / 2` .

A solution based on the answers is

```
out2 <- apply(expand.grid(seq_along(B), seq_along(B)), 1, \(i) 
              (max(A[, i]) * (B[[i[1]]] * B[[i[2]]])), simplify = FALSE)
names(out2) <- paste0("C_", do.call(paste, 
                                    c(expand.grid(seq_along(B), seq_along(B)), sep = ".")))
```

or

```
C <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
  lapply(1:5, function(j) {
    if (i == j) {
      C_i.i <- (A[,i] * B[[i]]^2)
    } else {
      C_i.j <- max(A[,i],A[,j]) * (unlist(B[[i]])*unlist(B[[j]]))
    }
  })
})
```

which however creates all possible scenarios and doubles the computational time since we know that C_1.2 = C_2.1 and ton calculation is needed.

Comment: its `max(A[,i], A[,j])` and not `max(A[,j], A[,j])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do this directly in `combn`

```
out <- combn(seq_along(B), 2, FUN = function(i) 
    (max(A[, i]) * (B[[i[1]]] * B[[i[2]]])), simplify = FALSE)
names(out) <- paste0("C_", combn(seq_along(B), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "."))
```

-checking the output with OP's output

```
> C_1.2<- max(A[,1],A[,2]) * (unlist(B[[1]])*unlist(B[[2]]))
> all.equal(out[[1]], C_1.2)
[1] TRUE
```

---

If we want all combinations, use `expand.grid`

```
out2 <- apply(expand.grid(seq_along(B), seq_along(B)), 1, \(i) 
    (max(A[, i]) * (B[[i[1]]] * B[[i[2]]])), simplify = FALSE)
names(out2) <- paste0("C_", do.call(paste, 
    c(expand.grid(seq_along(B), seq_along(B)), sep = ".")))
```

Comment: Thanks that partially do the trick, however this code does not calculate the `Ci,i` i.e. `C_1.1,C_2.2.,...,C_5.5`, which is what im trying to do.

Comment: @nickolakis `combn(1:5, 2)` doesn't give the `i,i`, for that you need `expand.grid` or `expand_grid` or `outer`.  Wouldn't that give unnecessarily create the 2 1 and 1 2

Comment: thanks, that works similar in a way I found, added both in my update.

Comment: Since your first answer is less computationally consuming. Is it possible to add a second calculations that only finds the `Ci,i`?

Comment: We can append the other combinations

Comment: @nickolakis you can add to the `combn` output `lapply(seq_along(B), \(i)  (max(A[, i]) * (B[[i]] * B[[i]])))`